# iOS, UIBarButtonItem: Custom label bound to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I have an issue with attaching a custom label bound to my UIBarButtonItem. My code:

```
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.00, 0.00, 10.0, 10.0)];
        lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:7];
        lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
        lbl.text=@"Subtypes available:";
        lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

        _btnSubtypes.enabled=YES; // UIBarButtonItem
        _btnSubtypes.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu / %lu",[_ucqc returnQuantityOfListedSubtypes:_coin],[_ucqc returnPureQuantityOfSubtypesInType:_coin]];
        [_btnSubtypes setAction:@selector(navigateToSubtypes)];
        [_btnSubtypes.customView addSubview:lbl];
```

This code is executed in `viewWillAppear` method. So, it doesn't set label. What's wrong with it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think is better in order to custom use UIButton than UIBarButtonItem. In your code you don't have any customView. If you insert a NSLog statements you can see than is nil.

```
[_btnSubtypes.customView addSubview:lbl];
NSLog(@"have I go customView? %@",[_btnSubtypes.customView description]);
```

You should change this:

```
  _btnSubtypes.customView=lbl;
```

But It´s posible the result not match with you expect.